# How to automatically assign access and allow staff to login and edit their page

Tags: active-directory, ldap, access-control, user-permissions

My workplace are looking wants each staff to have a web profile. Staff should be able to login and edit the profile. User accounts are on LDAP Active Directory. I'm trying to help research the options. I was wondering how large companies manage such things, there must be a way to automatically grant individuals access to their page, without having to set access for each one individually.

I've been trying to find out how that's done for a while. I only got as far as finding out that potentially one option may be to create fields on active directory. Though I'm not sure if it's possible to restrict access to particular fields.

My workplace are not keen on granting access to active directory or adding fields there, so I'm wondering if it's possible to create pages in a stand alone site, or a CMS like Drupal/WordPress/Umbraco, and grant people access. Is there a better way to manage the process instead of manually granting each user access to their profile page?

I've limited understanding of server side stuff, and thought experts on here may be able to help me understand the options.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a Wiki site, that each user can have their own space, while teams can have shared spaces. Moreover, users don't need to have knowledge of HTML to create nice looking pages.

There are a lot of choices of wiki, large companies I had worked with use https://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence, but it is not free.

In terms of open source solutions, I found this module for Drupal, https://www.drupal.org/project/commons_wikis

On the home page of commons_wikis, it says it has been merged into Drupal Commons. So you need to install Drupal Commons if you want to try it out. And from the module list of Drupal Commons, you can find it provides two Wiki modules. Here is the list https://docs.acquia.com/commons/module

Comment: Thanks for the info hailong. It's not so much a Wiki site for individuals and teams. It's for public facing profile with a bio, link to their website, contact details, etc, as part of or integrated with company website with other info. And how best to manage their access using their active directory accounts.